# Check if Future is complete

Tags: dart

Before 'm3' you could check if a Future was completed with 'completer.future.isComplete' this seems to be gone. Is there a replacement? or do I need to save it myself then 
(it seems inside the _CompleterImpl there is still a field '_isComplete' but its not exposed

Comment: What is the use case? True, `isComplete` is gone, but there might be a  n easy workaround. Can you tell us why you need to check if a future is complete?

Comment: I have some kind of "transform" action, which is called every rendering frame (a "Tween"). which uses a future inside to tell someone who is interested when the transform is complete. If the tween still exists its "transform" action is still called, but gets immediately canceled when "future.isComplete". Of course I could just do some flag of my own,...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With M3 Dart, it's best to just use your own flag.

```dart
future.whenComplete(() {
  tweenCompleted = true;
});
```

Dart is a single threaded language so there is no race condition here.
Note that the [action] function is called when this future completes, whether it does so with a value or with an error.

Comment: Am I wrong, but in documentation I found only whenComplete method?   https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-async.Future#id_whenComplete

Comment: You're not wrong @raiym - the language has changed a bit since this question was posted, and the method is now called `whenComplete`.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to [@Cutch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1232819/cutch)'s solution is to wrap the `Future` in a `Completer`:

```dart
Completer<T> wrapInCompleter<T>(Future<T> future) {
  final completer = Completer<T>();
  future.then(completer.complete).catchError(completer.completeError);
  return completer;
}

Future<void> main() async {
  final completer = wrapInCompleter(asyncComputation());
  if (completer.isCompleted) {
    final result = await completer.future;
    // do your stuff
  }
}
```

This approach is more resourceful since you can both await for the completion asynchronously and check whether the future is completed synchronously.

Answer (score 7):

Using an extension on Future and building on Hugo Passos' answer:

```
extension FutureExtension<T> on Future<T> {
  /// Checks if the future has returned a value, using a Completer.
  bool isCompleted() {
    final completer = Completer<T>();
    then(completer.complete).catchError(completer.completeError);
    return completer.isCompleted;
  }
}
```

Comment: nice! also, returning the completer instead of a bool allows for awaiting the completion as well :)