# Synchrounous way to check if Future completed

Tags: dart, dart-async

Is there is a synchronous way to check if a Future has completed in Dart?

Cheers!

Comment: Such functionality is not implemented.

Comment: Nope.  You perhaps could use a [`Completer`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-async/Completer-class.html) instead.  Another alternative would be to use [`FutureOr`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-async/FutureOr-class.html) instead of a `Future` and to make consumers check the type.  Neither is encouraged, though.

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496657/check-if-future-is-complete

Answer (score 1):

No.

There is deliberately no way to check synchronously whether a future has already completed.

You can obviously keep track yourself:

```
Foo result = null;
fooFuture.then((value) { result = value; });
...
/// later
if (result != null) ...
```

That still only works after the first microtask, because your callback won't get called any sooner than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Completer` class.

```dart
final completer = Completer();

myFuture
  .then(completer.complete)
  .catchError(completer.completeError);

if (completer.isCompleted) {
  // Future has completed
}
```